# How to get all selected option text from multi select Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have problem in get all selected option in multi select

```
<select multiple="" title="" class="" id="fm_delivery_or_collection" name="fm_fields[fm_delivery_or_collection][]">
  <option value="90">Delivery or Collection1</option>
  <option value="91">Delivery or Collection2</option>
  <option value="92">Delivery or Collection3</option>
</select>
```

Bellow is my code and its return me only first selected option

```
var select = form.find('select')

for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) 
        {
            var s_id = jQuery(select[i]).attr('id');
            var str="",i;

            var e = document.getElementById(s_id);
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

            var name = jQuery(select[i]).attr('name')
            var str1 = jQuery(select[i]).attr('id').replace("fm_"," ")
            requestString += "<b>"+str1.replace(/_/g," ")+"</b>" + ':' +strUser+"<br>";
        }
```

So please suggest me how can i get all selected option text and where I make mistake ?

Comment: The value of `select multiple` (or `select[select.selectedIndex]`) is an array...

Comment: The answers are overly complicated. You can get all selected options text using .map(). `$("select :selected").map(function (i, element) { return jQuery(element).text(); }).get();`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your comment *`please suggest me how can i get all selected option text`*, [**So you can try this**](http://jsfiddle.net/r4zq2/1/):

```
$("#fm_delivery_or_collection option:selected").each(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.length) {
    var selText = $this.text();
    console.log(selText);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 39):

do all in one line now

```
var text = $('#selector option:selected').toArray().map(item => item.text).join();
```

it return like this:

```
text1,text2,text3,text4
```

Comment: Nice and simple solution. If you need a different output, join() accepts a separator as an argument. For exemple join(' | '), will ouput "text1 | text2 | text3 | text4".
And a slight improvement : jQuery recommands using $('#selector').find('option:selected'), because searching by ID alone relies on document.getElementById, which is very fast, while the full selector does not. If #selector refers to a select tag, you may also remove the unnecessary "option" from the selector for a bit more efficiency : https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

Answer (score 13):

```
// Return an array of the selected opion values
// select is an HTML select element
function GetSelectValues(select) {
  var result = [];
  var options = select && select.options;
  var opt;

  for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    opt = options[i];

    if (opt.selected) {
      result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

pass this function your select box as like..

```
var selectBox = document.getElementsById('fm_delivery_or_collection');
alert(GetSelectValues(selectBox ));
```

it will return the array of selected values

**By using Jquery**

```
$('select#fm_delivery_or_collection').val()
```

the `val` function called from the `select` will return an array if its a multiple.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
$("#fm_delivery_or_collection option").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('selected') == 'selected')
    {
        var name = $("#fm_delivery_or_collection").attr('name')
        var str1 = $("#fm_delivery_or_collection").attr('id').replace("fm_"," ")
        requestString += "<b>"+str1.replace(/_/g," ")+"</b>" + ':' +strUser+"<br>";
     }
})
```

Comment: see your iteration you are iterating through options and `options doesn't have id` and `name`. Can you see that?

Comment: Well you can add `.parent()` in that, try with it.

Comment: Oh yes you are right @Jai...thanx for suggestion...I have edited now

Answer (score 2):

```
 $("#id :selected").each(function (i,sel) {
   alert($(sel).text());
 });
```

Hope it Helps..

Answer (score 2):

[**try this link**](https://jsfiddle.net/pasuvan/qrqv06su/5/):

```
$("#selection option:selected").each(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.length) {
    var selText = $this.text();
    console.log(selText);
    $('#selected').append(selText+', ');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add this line of code:-

```
var reciever= jQuery('#to_select option:selected').toArray().map(item => item.text).join();
/* alert(reciever); */
```