# how to get option value and text of multiselect in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to get both options and values from multiselect as an array

**select box**

```
<div class="form-group" id="specialtyDiv">
   <label class="main">{{__('messages.Speciality')}}</label>
   <div class="input-group">
      {{ Form::select('specialities[]', $speciality_master, old('specialities') ?? '', ['class'=> 'form-control m-select2','id'=>'m_select2_speciality', 'data-plugin'=>'select2','multiple'=>true, 'style'=>'width:100%']) }}
   </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery** which tries fetches the option

```
$('.select2-tags').on('select2:select', function (e) {
  var specialty = $("#m_select2_speciality");
  var myArray = [];  

  $.each(specialty,function(i,val){
    myArray['text'] = specialty.text();
    myArray['value'] = specialty.val();
  });

  if(isNaN(e.params.data.id)){
      $('#addTagModal').modal();
      $('#addTagModal #tagTitle').val(e.params.data.id);

      $.each(myArray,function(index,json){
            $("#selectSpecialty").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", myArray.value).text(myArray.text));
        });
   }

      });
```

I want the output of myArray to be something like this

```
var myArray= [
                  { "value": "pune", "text": "Pune"  },
                  { "value": "mumbai", "text": "Mumbai"  },
                  { "value": "nashik", "text": "Nashik"  }
                ];
```

Please help me find the solution

**Edits**
@Ntiyiso Rikhotso's answer solved the issue, In-addition, I've changed this

```
$("#selectSpecialty").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", myArray.value).text(myArray.text));
```

to

```
$("#selectSpecialty").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", data[index].value).text(data[index].text));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all selected option text form multi select Using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972708/how-to-get-all-selected-option-text-form-multi-select-using-javascript)

Comment: It's not about just getting the text, but to fetch both text and value as an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should get you all the selected options

```
var data = [];
$(document).find('#m_select2_speciality option:selected').each(function(){
   var option = $(this);
    data.push({value : option.attr('value'), text : option.text()});
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked,  but do you know, why the dynamically appended option shows empty values?

Comment: Solved the issue, it was because of  mistakes in option append

Comment: Yes, to deal with dynamically added content, you need to use `$(document)`